# How to handle a JWT token on client side in .net core blazor app

Tags: jwt, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.1

I followed several guides on how to set up Authentication on my Web Api, and it does return a JWT when user sucessfully logs in. but what do I do with the token on the client side? the client side at the moment is a blazor server side web application.

I can't find any guides on the second half of adding authentication and authorization to .net core applications. I would like to be able to use the token and extend the authorization down to the user interface.

I suppose I would have to copy the secret key from the web api down to the web application to verify the token.

I want to be able to use the built in Authorization views for blazor, where do I start?